# Inherit callable objects with different arguments

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have this problem which looks quite weird... so maybe I am just getting the whole thing wrong -- in such case, please, let me know.

I have a base class which implements `__call__` method. This method does some pre-processing, then invokes an abstract `_call()` method and does some post-processing, like this:

```
class BaseCallable(object):

    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def _call(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def __call__(self, *args, *kwargs):
        # do some pre-processing
        result = self._call(*args, **kwargs)
        # do some post-processing
        return result
```

I would like to be able to subclass the base callable object adding a `call()` method, with a proper docstring, that accepts different arguments and then *bounces* onto `__call__`. I am having some issues as I should also change the signature of the concrete implementation of the `_call()`, e.g.:

```
class Sum(BaseCallable):

    def _call(self, x, y):
        return x + y

    def call(self, x, y):
        """Docstring."""
        return super(Sum, self).__call__(x, y)
```

I did like this and since `pylint` complains:

```
[pylint] W0221:Parameters differ from overridden '_call' method
```

I assume there is something *fishy* going on. Any suggestion for a better design? Maybe I should constrain the `_call()` and `__call__()` methods to accept only `**kwargs`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it complain about it not being `def call(self, x, y):`?

Comment: @SimeonVisser sorry, I messed up in copy&paste. Anyway, no, it complains because of different argument. I will post the error message.

Comment: doesn't that error just mean "your parameters are now `x,y` instead of `*args,**kwars` so it isn't callable in the same way" I think it's warning you that you made a restriction you fully intended to.

Comment: Yeah, the `_call` method in `Sum` can now only accept a few parameters whereas the signature of that method in `BaseCallable` suggests it can accept positional and keyword arguments. If you want these objects to be interchangeable then the signatures should match.

Comment: I see. Actually I understand the motivation behind the message, what I need advice about is how to design a class hierarchy which together flexible and safe. I think that the `**kwargs` way could actually work. I am making some tests right now and post the updates (eventually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code could work as you expect. It's just a warning to tell you that the parameters declared in subclass is different from declared in base class. I have read your comment, so I think there is no need for me to explain why IDE gives this warning.

But actually, what you want to do is to wrap the function `_call` generally, so it is not a normal base class but a special one.

In a word, you did it correctly at all.